# Stacked architecture in flutter

Tags: flutter, architecture, stacked

In flutter how to implement stacked architecture and services provided by stacked_services. use stacked routing for navigation and dialog service for dialogs in my flutter project.

I'm expecting please help me for using of stacked architecture and services provided by stacked_services. use stacked routing for navigation and dialog service for dialogs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new to `stacked`, here is a well-written article on it https://www.cinnamon.agency/blog/post/exploring_stacked_a_powerful_flutter_framework_for_building_well_structured.

Also, the most recent video from the creator of `stacked` at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06vVccZvGuo

Just get your hand-dirty and build some app with `stacked`, you can't learn swimming without getting wet.

Happy coding!